# Save all the values in a csv file from C language

Tags: c, csv, raspberry-pi

My purpose is to save the mV data into a csv file, my first aproach is this one:

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char n = 0;

void escriure_csv(char valor){
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("file.csv", "w+");
    fprintf(fp,"%d",valor);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
int main()
{   while(1)
 
    //(....) here there are other things

    uint8_t mV = (read_data*250)/1024; 
printf("mV: %u\n", mV);
n+=1;
escriure_csv(mV);
}
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to save the mV data into a csv, but when I open it again it returns me just the last value, I can imagine thats due to the fact that each time I acces to escriure_csv I open and close the document so the next time the pointer is in the same place.So for solving that I have done:

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char n = 0;

void escriure_csv(char valor){

}
int main()
{   
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen ("file.csv", "w+");
    while(1){
    
   //(....)
 
    uint8_t mV = (read_data*250)/1024; //en cas que tornes un 0 es perque el resultat es - o 0.
    printf("mV: %u\n", mV);
    n+=1;
    fprintf(fp,"%d",mV);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
    //escriure_csv(mV);
}
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

But in this case the file is empty...
Any ideas?

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions here about reading CSV files in C. Are you sure they don't help?

Comment: "The file is empty", if buffer isn't flushed and you won't ever exit that `while(1)` loop then data won't ever go to disk until your program terminates. Flush the buffer with `fflush()` or use the first solution but open then file with `a` instead of `w+` (BTW why `w+`?).

Comment: You open a file for writing, write one value and close it again. Then it has one value. Repeatedly.  What do you expect? Did you consider opening for appending?

Comment: @klutt Is that "reading" a typo? I think this is about "writing". Not very similar words to typo across .... ;-)

Comment: Eva, please apply indentation. One of your problems becomes more obvious if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved! The code is good, the problem is that I'm using the library bcm2835 with RPi4 and when it recieves 126 data stops working, so the actual problem is knowing how to solve
`bcm2835_init: gpio mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory`